# Обработать код ответа сервера на чужом сайте

Tags: javascript, php

Есть страница на сайте. С сайта надо получить информацию, а конкретно id записей. В коде страницы id не отображается, но он отображается в ответе сервера в виде json. Каким образом можно получить ответ сервера и обработать его если, доступ к сайту у меня только пользовательский. Было бы идеально если бы можно было обойтись только js в консоле, но я не знаю насколько это возможно. Я так понимаю, мне нужно с своего сервера отправить запрос, получить нужный мне ответ с json и уже обработать его на стороне сервера.

Comment: Точно так же, как и код страницы. Получение ответа с сервера для любой страницы делается одинаково

Comment: Я вроде как это понимаю, но не до конца. Поправьте меня если я не прав, в js за ответы сервера отвечает объект  XMLHttpRequest, но насколько я знаю в нём содержится информация полученная через ajax. Т.Е работая через консоль, обратившись к этому объекту мы не получим нужную инфу